# CGAL Delaunay Triangulation with Surface Mesh

Tags: c++, cgal, triangulation, delaunay

I am used to index based meshes of triangles and I would love to keep using them.

How do I create a Surface_mesh from Surface_mesh_default_triangulation_3
and a vector of points?
I tried this but failed

```
 typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_default_triangulation_3 Triangulation;

 typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>                      Kernel;
 typedef CGAL::Point_3<Kernel>                               Point;



 int main()
 {

     Triangulation tr;
     std::vector<Point> points;



    //how do I create Surface_mesh from points?
     tr.insert(points); //does sadly not work

    Surface_mesh mesh = tr.createMeshFromPoints(points); //doesnt work
}
```

if it is not possible to use a delaunay triangulation with surface mesh
is there an easy way to use it on a Polyhedron_3 Mesh and convert it a
surface mesh?

I realy just want the triangulated, indexbased version of a 3d point
cloud without including pcl into the project.

The project just needs a good, fast c++ triangulation of a randomly rotated spiral with 512 * i points in 3D. Wanted to try something new with ray traced data and I am a bit stuck. I could write an algorithm for triangulation myself, but we are using cgal now, and if it announces triangulation I am expecting cgal to offer it. To be honest cgal is one of the most unpleasant libs I ever worked with and I am used to ROS Code with PCL and Kinect Code from mechanical engineers.

Edit:
Try fade2d . It is free but not opensource. It is fast and gives good results.

Comment: Your question is far from being clear. I think the most important part might be "I realy just want the triangulated, indexbased version of a 3d point cloud". The 3D triangulations in CGAL are pointers-based, but the `Vertex` type of the triangulation can be chosen to have the index of the original point. Would that suit your need?

And why do you talk about `Polyhedron_3` or `Surface_mesh`? The combinatorics of a 3D triangulation is very different from a surface mesh, and there is no possible conversion from one to the other.

Comment: As for the line `tr.insert(points);`, the correct way to insert a range of points is: `tr.insert(points.begin(), points.end())`. That API might be improved with the new features of C++20 (concepts, and ranges concepts).

Comment: Third thought after your question: one could write a `Vertex` type for the triangulation that does not actually store the point, but only a pointer to it in an existing sequence of points (like your `points` vector). That way, the triangulation would not store the geometry at all, but only the combinatorics of the triangulation. That `Vertex` type is still to be written.

Comment: Thank you for your help Irineau. I was kind of frustrated a 1am after reading the api and trying it for days. And my post was a bit rude. I am sorry.

In fact it i have a flat spiral as point cloud and I need it triangulated. The spiral is used to shoot rays through it, so I need the indices of the points in the triangulated version. 

Do you know a nice library which triangulates point clouds to index based meshes?

Comment: Do you have an example for this?

"triangulations in CGAL are pointers-based, but the Vertex type of the triangulation can be chosen to have the index of the original point"

Comment: Alternativ product, not open source, but runs on almost everything and can return an index list:

http://www.geom.at/runtime/